# Mobile Contexts for Information Retrieval

Tags: iphone, windows-mobile, information-retrieval, knowledge-management

I work with contexts for a Mobile Wiki Software. Contexts are used to serve the right information for a specific situation out of large pool of information units.

- For example: When you are at the
  customer, the system checks your
  location and presents you location
  based information.
- Another example: You are at the
  customer and the system checks your
  calendar to find appropriate
  information for your appointment there.

**Which other context resources (beside location and calendar data) are used for mobile (smartphone) software?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think ok:

- incoming and outgoing phone calls with contact based information and location based information.
- call logs with contact based, call note and location based informatiopn.
- sms/mms again with into / output to calendar data, contact data and location data.
- email with into / output to calendar data, contact data and location data.
- tasks and task lists.

Answer (score 1):

I guess address books are most important in such application.

Comment: Yes, which use can you (for example) imagine for address books?

Comment: on the same way your examples are going - When you are at the customer, find all the customers phone numbers. 

another idea is to find the closest friend where you are...

Comment: Cool, I'll make a prototype to test this. Thanks

Comment: Hi Stefan, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

browser bookmarks, preferences